# Column borders not extending to the bottom for a table of fixed height

Tags: html, css, flying-saucer

I am trying to produce a HTML template to precisely match the requirements of a customer. This HTML template is then converted to a PDF using [flyingsaucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/).

Specifically, I need a table to be a set height on the page. The table has to have columns, but no row lines except for on the header. (Hey, don't shoot me, the customer demands it!)

The CSS:

```
        #invoice-table {
            border: 1px solid darkblue;
            border-spacing: 0;
            clear: both;
            margin: 2mm 0mm;
            height: 100mm;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #invoice-table th, td { border-left: 1px solid darkblue; }
        #invoice-table th:first-child, td:first-child { border-left: none; }
        #invoice-table th { border-bottom: 1px solid darkblue; }
        #invoice-table td { vertical-align: top; font-size: 8pt; }
        th { text-align: center; font-weight: normal; }
        .amount { text-align: right; }
        .invoice_line { height: 6mm; }
        .invoice_line td, .invoice_line th { padding: 1mm; }
```

And the table:

```
    <table id="invoice-table">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="35mm" />
            <col />
            <col width="20mm" />
            <col width="20mm" />
            <col width="20mm" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr class="invoice_line">
            <th>Rate Class</th>
            <th>Rate and Driver Details</th>
            <th>Item/s</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="invoice_line">
            <td>Drivers</td>
            <td class="site">Charges for the provision of temporary resources (supply of driver/s)
                week ending 12th Oct 2013 for Getty Museum</td>
            <td class="amount">1</td>
            <td class="amount">&pound;341.63</td>
            <td class="amount">&pound;341.63</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="invoice_line">
            <td>Drivers</td>
            <td class="site">Charges for the provision of temporary resources (supply of driver/s)
                week ending 12th Oct 2013 for Staples Center</td>
            <td class="amount">1</td>
            <td class="amount">&pound;330.00</td>
            <td class="amount">&pound;330.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This works! Almost... !!!

Using flying saucer R8, this produces almost the exact required effect. However, there is a gap at the bottom of the table (see screenshot below). I am trying to get rid of that gap.

[image]

The gap does not appear on a browser. Is this a flyingsaucer bug or am I missing something? Or is there a better way to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this some time ago. Looking at the CSS, the solution appears to be one of setting border-collapse or box-sizing or both.

```
        #invoice-table {
            border: 0.5pt solid darkblue;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            clear: both;
            margin: 2mm 0mm;
            height: 100mm;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Comment: working great,very nice invoice table